# How to create a Windows 8 Metro App using Visual Studio?

Tags: windows-8

How does one create a new Windows 8 Metro application with custom styles in Visual Studio?

Comment: your question is not altogether clear- what is it exactly that you are trying to do, and can you edit your question accordingly?

Comment: @ethanlee16 I have edited the question as I understood as he wants to create windows 8 metro apps using visual studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not child's play, if you are familiar with Visual Studio development than you can go with MSDN to get through the same.

Try this link, I will give you additional useful links if I can find some similar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx

Best of luck.